# HOw to use JSONP to load external HTML page into light box?

Tags: jquery, html, json, jsonp, same-origin-policy

I am trying to build a simple webpage that on click of a button opens a lightbox on my website displaying another website.

Eg:
I want a button called News which when clicked by my user displays the CNN website inside a lightbox. I am using Framewarp for the lightbox (https://github.com/SiteOctopus/FrameWarp)

What i understand is that i need to do a JSONP implementation.
But i have never dealth with something like this in the past.

Could you please help me with a detailed explanation of how JSONP should be implemented into my website ?

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of things your lightbox should simply make use of an iframe of the cnn website as a jsonp request doesn't seem valid in any way or form for what you are trying to accomplish.